# Using HTTP Request for Google Dialogflow

Tags: request, http-post, dialogflow-es

https://api.dialogflow.com/v1/query?v=20150910&contexts=shop&lang=en&query=apple&sessionId=12345&timezone=America/New_York

Headers:
Authorization: Bearer YOUR_CLIENT_ACCESS_TOKEN

How do i use the above code to make a HTTP Request in Google Dialogflow? How do i add headers as a part of HTTP request

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/apps) application for sending POST request,

Select Post request in Postman Application,

Copy and paste URL https://api.dialogflow.com/v1/query?v=20150910&contexts=shop&lang=en&query=apple&sessionId=12345&timezone=America/New_York

In headers section, choose `Authorization` as key and paste the `Bearer YOUR_CLIENT_ACCESS_TOKEN`

Then, if you click **send** you will get the proper response in a body.

Comment: It gets in 401.

Comment: make sure this is for api v1 and you are passing valid token

Answer (score 2):

An easy start is to use curl from the command line as in the documentation:

```
curl \
-H "Authorization: Bearer YOUR_CLIENT_ACCESS_TOKEN" \
"https://api.dialogflow.com/v1/query?v=20150910&contexts=shop&lang=en&query=apple&sessionId=12345&timezone=America/New_York"
```

Just copy the whole thing and paste it into your command line and you will get a json response.

Ref: https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/agent/query#get_query_sample

Comment: How can we use it with Google Dialogflow? It doesn't make sense to me.