# Kotlin Using Dialogflow with Fuel for simple chatbot on Android

Tags: android, http, kotlin, dialogflow-es

I have been following this tutorial [on how to create a simple chatbox in Android Studio.](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-conversational-interface-for-android-with-dialogflow--cms-30845)

I have successfully created an entity on Dialogeflow and double checked that I copied the `ACCESS_KEY` correctly.

Here is my code:

```
FuelManager.instance.baseHeaders = mapOf(
            "Authorization" to "Bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN"
    )

    FuelManager.instance.basePath =
            "https://api.dialogflow.com/v1/"

    FuelManager.instance.baseParams = listOf(
            "v" to "20170712",                  // latest protocol
            "sessionId" to UUID.randomUUID(),   // random ID
            "lang" to "en"                      // English language
    )

    val human = ChatUser(
            1,
            "You",
            BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources,
                    R.drawable.ic_account_circle)
    )

    val agent = ChatUser(
            2,
            "Agent",
            BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources,
                    R.drawable.ic_account_circle)
    )

    my_chat_view.setOnClickSendButtonListener(
            View.OnClickListener {
                my_chat_view.send(Message.Builder()
                        .setUser(human)
                        .setText(my_chat_view.inputText)
                        .build()
                )

                // More code here
            }
    )
        Fuel.get("/query",
                listOf("query" to my_chat_view.inputText))
                .responseJson { _, _, result ->
                    val reply = result.get().obj()
                            .getJSONObject("result")
                            .getJSONObject("fulfillment")
                            .getString("speech")

                    my_chat_view.send(Message.Builder()
                            .setRight(true)
                            .setUser(agent)
                            .setText(reply)
                            .build()
                    )
                }
```

I have found that I am receiving a HTTP 404 error, which means that whatever path Fuel is creating is wrong or I'm missing a parameter.

I have double checked that the ACCESS TOKEN is correct and even created another just in case and updated the application.

When I run this program, it crashes the application. Only when I return the value of the query using a try catch statement did I find out it was because it was returning a 404 error. And also my logs show this aswell.

Anything that I am missing? This is my first time using Dialogflow.

I've been pulling my hair over this for the past 3 hours, looking at the logs and playing with try catch statements but still don't know what I'm missing.

[Dialogflow API Reference](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/agent) tells me that all I need is the Authorization token, Protocol version (I've tried both of them).

If anyone can help me out and needs more information let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching on stackoverflow, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49275959/3396971) answer that gave me the structure that I needed for my GET request.

And so I removed the FuelManager's basePath and baseParams from my query and hardcoded the GET request in the format specified by the link posted above.

```
Fuel.get("https://api.dialogflow.com/v1/query?v=20150910&lang=en&query="
                +chatView.inputText+"&sessionId=12345")
```

My only guess is that the baseParams and basePath where not correctly linked to the Fuel instance.